# How to add a photo in the navigation bar in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to add a photo in the navigation. On click on the photo should be navigating to edit user screen. I am using a tabbed page design, `Home, Map and Settings` are my tabbed pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ToolbarItems to add icon on the right hand side of the Navigationbar

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabPageSample.Views.MyTabbedPage">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="profileicon.png" Clicked="OnProfilePicClicked"/>
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage Title="HOME" />
    <ContentPage Title="MAP" />
    <ContentPage Title="SETTINGS" />
</TabbedPage>
```

In the Page's backend class you add event:

```
private void OnProfilePicClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Navigate to Edit Profile page here
}
```

**PS: Programatically:**

```
var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage(); 
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home()); 
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Map()); 
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings());

//Create Toolbar Item
var profilePicTollbarItem = new ToolbarItem()
{
    Icon = "profileicon.png"
};
profilePicTollbarItem.Clicked += OnProfilePicClicked;
tabbedPage.ToolbarItems.Add(profilePicTollbarItem);
```

The Result will look like:

[image]

Comment: I don't have a `TabbedPage.xaml`, but I have created Home.xaml, Map.xaml and Settings.xaml separately. Then in `MainPage.xaml.cs` I have used `var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
     tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home()); tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Map()); tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings()); `

Comment: In this case where do I need to add the `<ToolbarItem Icon="profileicon.png" Clicked="OnProfilePicClicked"/>`

Comment: You should be adding this ToolBar items in the Page which contains your tab children pages. In your case you would be adding this to the "tabbedPage" instance variable programatically. I think you are creating instance of TabbedPage programatically from the MainPage and then pushing this tabbedPage from the MainPage.

Comment: I have edited my answer on how to do this programatically, according to your implementation and code snippet.

Comment: This Worked mate, image appear in square shape, can we change this into circle shape ?

Comment: You would need to create custom renderer for ToolBarItem, to customize according to your need, if possible.

Comment: Ok, now the image is appearing the `MainPage.xaml` also which is my login page..any way we could remove from MainPage.xaml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192519/discussion-between-milang-and-soccerway).